# VeraCrypt: mount volume (partition) from command line without mounting filesystem?

Tags: command-line, filesystems, volume, mount, veracrypt

On macOs, I can mount a Veracrypt volume from the command line like this:

```
/Applications/VeraCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/VeraCrypt --mount /dev/rdisk2s4
```

In the GUI, there is also the option not to mount the filesystem, like this:

[image: Screenshot]

In this case only a new virtual device gets mounted, and you can then later mount the filesystem manually with e.g. `diskutil mount <device>`

Question: is there a way to specify this "do not mount filesystem" option on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Missed this at first in the help, but found it: `--filesystem=none`

So the command line becomes:

```
/Applications/VeraCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/VeraCrypt --mount /dev/rdisk2s4 --filesystem=none
```